# VHDL 3-bit sequence counter with T-Flip Flops

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am new to VHDL and I can't see a solution to my problem. I want to find a VHDL code for my 3-bit sequence counter with T Flip Flop's which goes: ..,0,4,5,7,6,2,3,1,0,... I made a truth table and minimized equations for T_FF like so:

[image]

T0=Q2 xor Q1 xor Q0;

T1=(Q2 xor Q1) and Q0;

T2= not(Q2 xor Q1) and Q0;

Then I draw the circuit:

[image]

Last VHDL:

T-FLIP FLOP

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity tff is
  port(
        clk: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        t: in std_logic;
        q: out std_logic
      );
end tff;

architecture behave of tff is
 -- signal q_reg: std_logic; --v registru
--  signal q_next: std_logic; --naslednje stanje
begin
 process
variable x: std_logic:='0';
 begin
wait on clk;
       if (clk' event and clk = '1') then
    if reset='1' then
    x:='0';
    else x:=t;
end if;
end if;
if (t = '1') then
q<=not x;
else 
q<=x;
end if;
end process;

end behave;
 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Gray counter

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity tff_gray is
  port(
        clk: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        q: inout std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
        --q: out std_logic
      );
end tff_gray;

architecture behave of tff_gray is
component tff is
  port(
        clk: in std_logic;
        reset: in std_logic;
        t: in std_logic;
        q: out std_logic
      );
end component;

  signal i0,i1,i2: std_logic; --v registru
  --signal q_next: std_logic; --naslednje stanje
begin
i0<=q(0) xor q(1) xor q(2);
i1<=q(0) and (q(1) xor q(2));
i2<=q(0) and not(q(1) xor q(2));
    Tff0: tff port map(clk, reset, i0, Q(0));
    Tff1: tff port map(clk, reset, i1, Q(1));
    Tff2: tff port map(clk, reset, i2, Q(2));
end behave;
```

I wrote this bunch of code of what I found over the internet. When I compiled my code it all went through without a problem but the simulation is wrong. I went through this code a lot of times and I don't know what is wrong. If anyone has any idea please share. 
I have mostly watched this [altera](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/vhdl/vhd-gray-counter.html) site and LBEbooks on YouTube.

Comment: Shouldn't `Q(0)` be just `q(0)`?

Comment: @Qiu VHDL is case insensitive...

Comment: Are you sure you want a T flip flop? Not a D flip flop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things. Firstly:

---

### T-FF aka toggle flip flop

You've got your [toggle flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#T_flip-flop) description incorrect.
A toggle flip flop flips the output if `T='1'`. so:

```
    signal q_int : std_logic := '0';
begin
    tff_proc: process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if t='1' then
                q_int <= not q_int;
            end if;
            -- reset statement
            if reset='1' then
                q_int <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    q <= q_int;
```

---

### redundant code

Don't combine `wait on clk` *and* `if (clk'event and clk='1')` as they do the same thing. Combining will cause issues. Refer to my example above for correct instantiations.

---

### component instantiation

You don't need to include the `component tff` code in your `tff_gray` entity. Just simply instantiate the entity directly from the library. e.g.

```
Tff0: entity work.tff port map(clk, reset, i0, q(0));
```

---

### bidirectional ports (`inout` type)

Using the `inout` type, which you use for the `q` of `tff_gray` can give problems in simulation and implementation. It should be `out`.

However, you must have encountered the `cannot read outputs` error. This is no longer an issue in VHDL-2008, so you should compile using VHDL-2008 mode.

Alternatively, you need to use intermediate signals, like I did in the example above. E.g.

```
signal q_int : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
[...]
q <= q_int;
```